# Здравствуйте! Выдает ошибку"Unsupported Java.Your build is currently configured to use Java 22 and Gradle8.4." Спасибо всем заранее!)Не судите строго)

Tags: java, gradle

[image] открываю Gradle wrapper settings там нет "distributionUrl" Может нужно переустановить Intelliji?.

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)

Comment: Какая у вас версия Intellij Idea?  Согласно [официальной информации](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2024/03/java-22-and-intellij-idea/), Java 22 поддерживается в IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1 Beta.